# Add Windows to Ubuntu grub

Tags: partitioning

I would like to add Windows to grub? and have already tried the Boot Repair tool:

http://paste2.org/5OFsYINv

```
Boot Info Script cfd9efe + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 26Apr2016]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos1)/grub. It also embeds following components:

    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext2
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the boot sector of sda1 
                       and looks at sector 843192 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img. core.img is at this location and looks for 
                       (,msdos1)/grub. It also embeds following components:

                       modules
                       -------------------------------------------------------
                       fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
                       -------------------------------------------------------
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 16392 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg /casper/vmlinuz.efi 
                       /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

ubuntu-vg-root: ________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab

ubuntu-vg-swap_1: ______________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 149.1 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       999,423       997,376  83 Linux
/dev/sda2           1,001,470   312,580,095   311,578,626   5 Extended
/dev/sda5           1,001,472   312,580,095   311,578,624  8e Linux LVM


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 GiB, 4004511744 bytes, 7821312 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          2,048     7,821,311     7,819,264   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 7024025a-3d60-4207-abce-c85ac905acfb   ext4       
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 95d424f5-afb1-4477-8a25-0475e12383dc   swap       
/dev/sda1        c49321d6-0e68-4e49-aff2-feb95b64fe1e   ext2       
/dev/sda5        2QAm1N-Fts6-3W00-OjqZ-EGVY-5jni-M9KmOt LVM2_member 
/dev/sdb1        20E7-9D14                              vfat       UBUNTU 16_0

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  9 20:06 ata-SAMSUNG_HM160HI_S1WWJ9BZ910170 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 20:06 ata-SAMSUNG_HM160HI_S1WWJ9BZ910170-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 20:06 ata-SAMSUNG_HM160HI_S1WWJ9BZ910170-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 20:06 ata-SAMSUNG_HM160HI_S1WWJ9BZ910170-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 20:06 dm-name-ubuntu--vg-root -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 20:06 dm-name-ubuntu--vg-swap_1 -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 20:06 dm-uuid-LVM-0cawvvxTdfN175ebJMEvc90iGHQr3vZI6W73Zq3PnHOn9YTNZYarzldju8TRVC9y -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 20:06 dm-uuid-LVM-0cawvvxTdfN175ebJMEvc90iGHQr3vZIyldV6FKfEvkjfO2R2Uk1yGVfJV7SEML9 -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 20:06 lvm-pv-uuid-2QAm1N-Fts6-3W00-OjqZ-EGVY-5jni-M9KmOt -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  9 20:06 usb-SanDisk_Cruzer_Blade_20051737531B14029A88-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 20:06 usb-SanDisk_Cruzer_Blade_20051737531B14029A88-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  9 20:06 wwn-0x50f000002a910170 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 20:06 wwn-0x50f000002a910170-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 20:06 wwn-0x50f000002a910170-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  9 20:06 wwn-0x50f000002a910170-part5 -> ../../sda5

========================= "ls -R /dev/mapper/" output: =========================

/dev/mapper:
control
ubuntu--vg-root
ubuntu--vg-swap_1

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1        /boot                    ext2       (rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl)


============================= sda1/grub/grub.cfg: ==============================
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no Windows installation to add, unless it's on a disk that's disconnected or otherwise invisible. Chances are you accidentally wiped it out. If you have critical personal data on your hard disk, ***STOP USING UBUNTU IMMEDIATELY!*** You may be able to recover *some* of your data with the help of [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) or something similar, but this is likely to be a tedious task. You'll also need a spare disk to hold the recovered files.

I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but unless you have a second disk that's not showing up in Boot Repair for some reason, it looks like Windows is gone.

Incidentally, pasting the Boot Info Script/Boot Repair output in your question is redundant with providing the pastebin link, and makes your question harder to read. I won't edit your question to remove the redundant output, but you might want to keep this in mind in the future.